# Permission to add contact data, not edit existing

Tags: permissions

We got a request to add a role for users to be able to add contact data but not edit the existing. For instance: contact has first name, last name and email filled in. Users with this role should be able to add another email, add address and telephone number, but not edit the name, not existing email field.

I honestly wouldn't know where to start with existing code. I mean: is there a way to accomplish this without using a custom extension?

(using up to date drupal 7 and CiviCRM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of accomplishing this more refined permission stuff involves thinking outside of the civi box and using Drupal Webforms (and perhaps Views)

Eg, build a Views based search, such that the results load up a webform with the cid in the url, this loads that contact on to the webform at which point you have total control over which fields are editable and which are only viewable.

Comment: thank you for confirming more or less the direction to think